# Best method to transfer two int percentage values over a CAN bus

Tags: atmega, c, can

I have two integers:

- int A is a value from -100 until 0  and
- int B is a value from 0 to 100

What is the most effective way to put this into a CAN message and decode it again at the other microcontroller?

For the CAN message I have this structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t id;
    uint8_t length : 4;
    uint8_t data[8];
} CANmessage;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need *int* to store those values - a simple *int8_t* will do.  *int8_t* can store from -128 to +127.

Then just place *int8_t A* in data[0], *int8_t B* in data[1] (cast them to *uint8_t*) and set the length to 2.  Read them from there at the other end as uint8_t (cast them to *int8_t*), and Robert's your mother's brother.

You don't even need to restrict it to int8_t though - you could use just uint8_t throughout.  The values you have are -100-0 and 0-100.  Those are both ranges of 101 values.  101 fits into 8 unsigned bits easily. As long as both ends agree that the positive value in data[0] is a negative value (store -34 as 34) then use it as such (subtract data[0] from 0 so 34 becomes -34) then you don't need to transmit the - sign.

Comment: Or in general, char = int8_t

Comment: @Mike if you have included <stdint.h> (which he must have since he's using uint8_t).

Comment: @Mike In general, `char` may be either `int8_t` or `uint8_t`, depending on the system and compiler.  Unless you're actually storing characters, you should always use one of the latter.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle `char` will always be 8 bits, but whether it's signed is implementation defined, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default

Comment: @sapi - char isn't always 8-bits.  Some embedded compilers (for SHARC DSPs as one example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Harvard_Architecture_Single-Chip_Computer) have 32-bit for all of `char`, `int` and `long`.

Answer (score 6):

You want to send two numbers that each can have 101 different values.  There are therefore 101 x 101 = 10,201 different possible overall values you can send.  Log2(10,201) = 13.3, so you can always fit your message into 14 binary bits.  Data on a CAN bus is sent in chunks of 8 bit bytes, so you need a minimum of two of those.  The simplest encoding scheme would be to use one byte for each value.

There is significant overhead with each CAN bus frame, so whether you send 2 or 3 or 4 or more data bytes in one frame doesn't make that much difference in the overall protocol.  If you really want to minimize the CAN frame lengths, see if you can encode the information in the frame ID.  If this is the only information that your CAN bus will carry, then you have another 11 bits of ID beyond the 0 to 8 optional data bytes in a standard frame, and 29 bits of ID beyond the data bytes in a extended frame.  You could, for example, use standard data frames with one data byte each.  That gives you 11 bits of ID plus 8 bits of data for a total of 19 bits you can control.  That gives you 5 bits beyond your raw data you can use as a opcode or something.

Comment: +1 Although you might want to highlight "if this is the only information that your CAN bus will carry" in bold. Doing it this way could also confuse certain debugging tools (there would be no way to know this except to test with the available tools, though).